# ios binary .app file not clickable

Tags: ios, xcode, binary, application-loader, .app

This is my first time putting an app on the itunes app store.  I've tested on a device and created the binary, but when I use Application Loader to upload the binary I see the binary is lighted-out and un-clickable.  Also, when I bring up the binary .app file in Xcode it has a big circle with a slash through it.  What does this mean, and how do I fix it?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The crossed out icon means "this file cannot be executed". This is normal, since the app and your Mac have different architectures.